# CompareAttribute of ASP.NET MVC 3.0

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I am using MVC-3.0. I need to compare 2 model values for equality like password, confirm password. So, I used the `CompareAttribute`. I am also using a lot of jQuery libraries. When the model values are compared(I am using `CompareAttribute`) and if the values are not same the `CompareAttribute` pops an error message in to the UI.

Now the problem is even if I clear and provide same values after I get the error message, the message is not cleared from the screen. The code still smells error in the values provided. I have run out of probable reasons for this behavior.

Need help to resolve this.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Did you upgrade your project to jquery 1.5 by any chance? Doing that broke my client side validation that came shipped with visual studio (had issues with compare attribute and few others). Apparently the validation that comes with visual studio isn't compatible with new jquery - http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/aspnet-mvc/general/jquery-1-5.aspx .

Comment: Hey Maciej, I have updated version of jQuery here http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.5.js in my solution.

Comment: I still have the same problem.

Comment: hmm I'm not sure what to tell you - I had a similar issue with the compare attribute. Downgrading to jquery 1.4.4 fixed it (apparently there is an update of the jquery validator that works with 1.5 but i have not tried it)